# Instantiating Objects & the relation of Child/Parent classes

Tags: java, class, object, parent-child, instantiation

So, I'm trying to understand some concepts here.

1) The general "syntax" (if you will) of creating a new object.  For example, which of the following is "correct" (I know there's more than one way to instantiate an object):

```
//1) ChildClass obj = new ParentClass();

//2) ParentClass obj = new ChildClass();
```

I know that the following two are "legal," but I can't understand the difference between instantiating an object when it comes to Child/Parent classes

(I already know that these two are okay):

```
ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
ParentClass obj = new ParentClass();
```

2) Basically, what I'm trying to ask is "Which *ClassName* refers to the class that the object is instantiated from/on (wording? sorry...), and which *ClassName* does the object belong to?"

My apologies if this doesn't really make sense.  I tried wording it the best I can.

(Some background: I am currently taking the first "course" of Object-Oriented Java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ChildClass` extends from `ParentClass`, you can do

```
ParentClass obj = new ChildClass();
```

but not the other way around.

The left hand side of this declaration is placing a variable named `obj` of declared or static type `ParentClass` into the current scope. The right hand side is assigning the variable a reference to a `new` object of dynamic type `ChildClass`. A `ChildClass` object is being instantiated and assigned to a variable of type `ParentClass`.

In other words, with the variable `obj`, for the compiler to be happy, you'll only have access to the method declared on its declared type, ie. `ParentClass`. If you want to call `ChildClass` methods, you'll need to cast it.

```
((ChildClass)obj).someChildClassMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

What I'm still having some trouble understanding, though, is really the difference between declaring/instantiating objects. 

For example, what is the difference between:

    Pig pig1 = new Pig();
    Animal pig1 = new Pig();

(assuming that Pig is a child-class of Animal)

Comment: @Bryan You are welcome. In both cases, you create a `Pig` object on the heap. In the first example, the object is assigned to a reference of type `Pig` so you can access all `Pig` (and inherited) methods and fields. In the second example, it is assigned to a reference of type `Animal`, so you are restricted to the methods and fields it inherits from that type.

Comment: @Bryan You can still cast the reference to another type to get access to the methods.