# Which is parent and child class?

Tags: java, android, class

I usually used to instantiate class like this

```
Classname instancename = new Classname();
```

but below lines are confusing me...

So please explain me which class is inside which class?

**which is parent and child class from this below code. list or array list?**

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

**which is parent and child class from this below code. Sharedpreference or Editor?**

```
SharedPreferences mapViewSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(foldername, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mapViewSharedPrefs.edit();
```

Comment: In Java parent-child relationship usually refers to classes **inherited** from other classes.  None of your examples have anything to do with [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating Objects & the relation of Child/Parent classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863295/instantiating-objects-the-relation-of-child-parent-classes)

Answer (score 0):

In Java a child class is a class that inherit from an other class called a "parent" class.

You need to look at the documentation to figure this out. Let me give you an example. For the first one you need to look for ArrayList. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
You can see here that ArrayList is a class that implement the List interface. List is not a parent class but an Interface that ArrayList implements.

For the second one SharedPreferences.Editor shows you that Editor is an inner class of SharedPreferences. So they dont have a "parent/child" relationship either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of NameValuePair...you could just as easily have a list of Obejct, or a list of Date.

The list is the container object, and whats inside the '< >' specifies what *TYPE* of objects it holds.

Also in Java 1.7 they let us get lazy and you can drop the second parameter and just use:

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
```

Example: Lets create 2 lists

```
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Marbles> marbleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

now lets create 2 objects

```
    Marble blueMarble = new Marble();
    Checker redChecker = new Checker();
```

We can put both into the *objectList* since they are both objects. However we can only put the *blueMarble* into the *marbleList*, the checker is an invalid Type for that list. Typing allows you to control what data is valid, So later on in the code you dont have to check the object class type when you extract from the list.

EDIT: From your added comments to the original question. Editor is the Inner class. Unless it extends SharedPreferences, it is not a child class of SharePreferences

Comment: Because both Marble and Checker ""extends"" Object. But you could better have an extra Object to make the thing more clear.